# Pymongo $in + aggregate with regex not working in pymongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am running the following query in Mongo shell :

```
db.coll.aggregate([ { "$match" : {   "_id":{"$in" : [/^4_.*/,/^3_.*/]}}},
                 { "$unwind" : "$rp"},
                 {"$group":{"_id": "$_id", "rp": { "$push":  "$rp" }}} , {"$limit":120}],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

which is working correctly. But when I am trying the same in pymongo as :

```
ids_list = [3,4]
ids_list = ["^" + str(c_id) + "_.*" for c_id in ids_list]

pipe = [ { "$match" : {   "_id":{"$in" : ids_list}}},
                { "$unwind" : "$rp"},
                {"$group":{"_id": "$_id", "rp": { "$push":  "$rp" }}} , {"$limit":500}] 

res = list(db.coll.aggregate(pipeline = pipe,allowDiskUse=True))
```

which is not working. I am new to Mongo queries.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the for loop where each element is compiled using **re** module i.e.

```
ids_list = [re.compile("^" + str(c_id) + "_.*") for c_id in ids_list]
```

and it worked :)